# Cloud Balancing Optaplanner: implement an overconstrained planning

Tags: java, optimization, load-balancing, optaplanner

I'm trying to implement a simple cloud balancing system with an Overconstrained plannig with the Optaplanner with java.

favorite
I'm trying to implement a simple cloud balancing system with an Overconstrained plannig with the Optaplanner library for Java.
I mapping the model to my problem (vehicles and assets) doing a variables substitution cpuPower -> weight, memory -> volume.
After rules definition for not exceed any of this 2 variables, the drl file:

```
package org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver;
    dialect "java"

import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScoreHolder;

import org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.Mission;
import org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.Vehicle;
import org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.Asset;

global HardSoftScoreHolder scoreHolder;

// ############################################################################
// Hard constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "requiredVolumeTotal"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        $vehicle : Vehicle($maxVolume : maxVolume)
        Number( $totalReqVolume : intValue() > $maxVolume ) from accumulate 
            ( Asset( vehicle == $vehicle , $volume : volume),
            sum($volume)) 
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -($totalReqVolume -$maxVolume));
end

rule "requiredWeightTotal"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        $vehicle : Vehicle($maxWeight : maxWeight)
        Number( $totalReqWeight : intValue() > $maxWeight ) from accumulate 
            ( Asset( vehicle == $vehicle , $weight : weight),
            sum($weight)) 
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -($totalReqWeight -$maxWeight));
end
```

If I use the simple example, I receive a response with all processes asigned although if some of this cannot be assigned to computers. For this problem, optaplanner purpuse is to change the implementation to a **overconstained plannig**. The documentation says:

> - *Add a additional score level (usually a medium level between the hard    and soft level) by switching Score type.*
> - *Make the planning variable nullable.*
> - *Add a score constraint on the new level (so usually a medium    constraint) to penalize the number of unassigned entities (or a  weighted sum of them).*

I'm doing the nullable annotation and the check in the compare method:

```
 @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"computerRange"},
        strengthComparatorClass = CloudComputerStrengthComparator.class,
        nullable = true)
public CloudComputer getComputer() {
    return computer;
}
```

_

```
@Override
public int compare(CloudComputer a, CloudComputer b) {
     if (a == null || b == null)
         return 0;
    return new CompareToBuilder()
            .append(a.getMultiplicand(), b.getMultiplicand())
            .append(b.getCost(), a.getCost()) // Descending (but this is debatable)
            .append(a.getId(), b.getId())
            .toComparison();
}
```

Whith this changes the processes after the solve method are all unasigned and the solution are incorrect cause ever is 0soft/0hard.

How can define a new constraint (with medium level) to penalize the number of unassigned entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using `HardMediumSoftScoreHolder` in your DRL and `HardMediumSoftScore` in your domain. Take a look at the hospital bed planning example for the DRL rule.